# Set a new name for the Spark executor pod in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin and Apache Spark on Kubernetes. After creating the Spark interpreter Pod, which works as a Spark driver, it attempts to launch 2 executors. However, in the pod logs, I'm encountering an error:

```
Exception when notifying snapshot subscriber.

java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception: string index out of range: 63
...
```

From my understanding, this error is related to the long name of the pod. Therefore, **I need to configure new name for the Spark executor pod in Kubernetes**. I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue!

I expect that after changing the names of the pods, the error will be resolved. It's possible that there might be an alternative solution to address it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the spark executor is by default based on the application name and a kubernetes generated id that ensure unicity in the cluster + -exec-$id where $id is the identifier of the executor defined by spark.

Basically, you need to have an app name + kubernetes generated id size <= 47 because -exec-[0-9]{1,10} will be always there, and has 16 characters, and total size accepted is 63.

So, if you have an app named foo, the executors pod names will be something like:

> foo-de0d85892012de3b-exec-1

> foo-de0d85892012de3b-exec-2
> ...

Now, this name should not be higher than 63 characters, so either:

- rename the app (spark.app.name) so the app name + kubernetes generated id won't be higher than 47
- use the option `spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix` in order to set a prefix yourself without leaving it to kubernetes, then the name will be podNamePrefix-exec-[0-9]{1,10}

Note that the second option could be tricky because you need to ensure that there is a unique kind of job in the cluster or you need to implement the logic of unicity on your side.

See more https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#configuration

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response with descriptions of several possible solutions to the problem. The solution involving renaming spark.app.name helped to resolve the issue!